# Как сделать, чтобы Notepad не был по умолчанию расширения .class

Tags: java

Как сделать, чтобы Notepad не был по умолчанию расширения .class

Comment: Удалить ассоциацию `.class` к этой программе

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Открыть командную строку (нажать `Win+R`, написать *cmd* и нажать  `Enter`)
2. Написать *assoc .class=* и нажать  `Enter`